# Exception when creating new Iphone/Ipad window in MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop

I get this exception every time i try to create a new Iphone/Ipad solution?

I have been following the guides and have both XCode, interface builder and IOS SDK installed.

Any clues are welcome:)

> System.ApplicationException: Can't create display binding for mime type: application/vnd.apple-interface-builder
>         at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.NewDocument (System.String defaultName, System.String mimeType, System.IO.Stream content) [0x00000] in :0 
>         at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.FileTemplate.CreateFile (MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.FileDescriptionTemplate newfile, MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String directory, System.String language, System.String name) [0x00000] in :0 
>         at MonoDevelop.Ide.Templates.FileTemplate.Create (MonoDevelop.Projects.SolutionItem policyParent, MonoDevelop.Projects.Project project, System.String directory, System.String language, System.String name) [0x00000] in :0 
>         at MonoDevelop.Ide.Projects.NewFileDialog.OpenEvent (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00000] in :0

Comment: I'm having the same problem, fresh install:<br />
<br />
Snow Leopard 10.6.5<br />
Xcode 3.2.5 and iOS SDK 4.2 <br /> 
Mono 2.8.2 <br />
Mono Develop 2.4.1 <br />
MonoTouch 3.2.4

Anyone have <i>any</i> idea about this?

Comment: I have same problem. 

I removed my mac 2 times and maybe 5-10 times tried removing ~/.config/MonoDevelop/addin and remove install program again. Same problem, same problem. I seems time to start learn Obj C. :(

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are trying to create a new file, not a new project/solution.